# Image file not deleted when object with ImageField field is deleted

Tags: django, imagefield

I've got a model `Picture` with an `ImageField`. When deleting an instance of `Picture`, the file set in the `ImageField` is not deleted.

Is it a bug? How can I do it?

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Django Admin to delete files when I remove an object from the database/model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Deletion of files associated with `FileField`s and `ImageField`s was *intentionally* removed in Django 1.3. See [ticket #6456](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6456). Django uses transactions extensively to prevent data corruption if something goes wrong with the request. If a deletion transaction is rolled-backed, after the file has been deleted from the filesystem, then you now have a record pointing to a non-existent file. All tickets asking for automatic deletion to return have been summarily marked "Won't Fix", so this is not going to change.

For workarounds, see [this previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab).

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions?

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="pics")

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image.delete()
        super(Picture, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then lets manually create and delete this..

```
image = "./image.jpg"
picture = Picture.objects.create(image=File(open(image, "r"))
picture.save()
```

Then delete it?

`picture.delete()`

HTH

Comment: Although this answer is already quite old: line 5 in the first codeblock should be `self.image.delete()`

Comment: And it better use signals as it doesn't work for `Picture.objects.filter(...).delete()` for example.