# Delete image from media when object is deleted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When I delete an object from my database, the image previously uploaded stays in the media directory. I would like to delete it automatically.

**Here is my model:**

```
class Door(models.Model) :
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='119.99')
```

**Here is my delete view:**

```
def door_delete(request, door_id) :
    door = get_object_or_404(Door, id=door_id)
    door.delete()
    return redirect("/dashboard/doors")
```

I have tried to instert before `door.delete()` line `door.image.delete()` but that hasn't worked out as far I as know.

Please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456666/3776299

Comment: A possible scenario: two `Door`s have the *same* `image`. So it is quite unsafe to simply delete the file.

Comment: I would advice *not* to do this at the `.delete()` function (it is furthermore sometimes possible to *bypass* functions like `.save()` and `.delete()` anyway). But write a command that occasionaly checks what media is no longer used, and removes these.

Comment: I did exactly what the post suggested but that didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 5):

do as below,

```
def door_delete(request, door_id):
    door = get_object_or_404(Door, id=door_id)
    if door.image:
        door.image.delete()
    door.delete()
    return redirect("/dashboard/doors")
```

Reference : [How do I get Django Admin to delete files when I remove an object from the database/model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab)