# deleting image from a child element is deleting it from the parent

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models Post and event

Below is my post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True, max_length=450)  
    message = models.TextField(max_length=3000)  
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images/')
```

and then I have a Events model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='cook')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='recipe')      
    date = models.DateField()    
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now in below is the CreateView for my Event

```
class CreateEvent(IsVerifiedMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = 'event/event_form.html'
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        event = self.object
        user = self.request.user
        today = datetime.date.today()
        if today + datetime.timedelta(days=3) <= event.date <= today + datetime.timedelta(days=30):
            event.user = user
            slug = self.kwargs['slug']
            post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
            event.post = post
            event.image = post.post_image ###########THIS IS WHERE THE EVENT GETS ITS IMAGE           
            event.save()            
        else:
            form.add_error(field="date", error="The date has to be more than or equal to 3 days and less than 30 days")
            return super().form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            return url_
```

> Now the problem is when I delete a event. It is deleting the post_image. Why is this happening. How Can I stop this from happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model actually violates a guideline of database normalization, since you have an unnecessary redundancy between `Event` and `Post`. `Event` is linked to `Post`, so having the same field "in sync" can cause many integrity errors such as the one you are facing.

The best way to handle this is to remove the `image` field from `Event`, and reference the image instead via `event_instance.post.post_image.url`.

Otherwise, there is no reason why your child should be deleting its parents image, [unless you are using Django < 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456666/3345051). This would be because in the older versions, Django would delete an image if the associated model instance was deleted - and since you are copying the image path from one model to another, the url is the same.