# Django delete FileField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building a web app in Django. I have a model that uploads a file, but I can not delete the file. Here is my code:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='id', related_name="id_user2")
    song = models.FileField(upload_to='/songs/')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/pictures/', blank=True)
    date_upload = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # You have to prepare what you need before delete the model
        storage, path = self.song.storage, self.song.path
        # Delete the model before the file
        super(Song, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        # Delete the file after the model
        storage.delete(path)
```

Then, in `python manage.py shell` I do this:

```
song = Song.objects.get(pk=1)
song.delete()
```

It deletes the record from the database but not the file on server.
What else can I try?

Thanks!

Comment: What about using the default_storage directly? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Before Django 1.3, the file was deleted from the filesystem automatically when you deleted the corresponding model instance. You are probably using a newer Django version, so you'll have to implement deleting the file from the filesystem yourself.

#### Simple signal-based sample

My method of choice at the time of writing is a mix of `post_delete` and `pre_save` signals, which makes it so that obsolete files are deleted whenever corresponding models are deleted or have their files changed.

Based on a hypothetical `MediaFile` model:

```
import os
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class MediaFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(_("file"),
        upload_to=lambda instance, filename: str(uuid.uuid4()))


# These two auto-delete files from filesystem when they are unneeded:

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=MediaFile)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes file from filesystem
    when corresponding `MediaFile` object is deleted.
    """
    if instance.file:
        if os.path.isfile(instance.file.path):
            os.remove(instance.file.path)

@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=MediaFile)
def auto_delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes old file from filesystem
    when corresponding `MediaFile` object is updated
    with new file.
    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return False

    try:
        old_file = MediaFile.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).file
    except MediaFile.DoesNotExist:
        return False

    new_file = instance.file
    if not old_file == new_file:
        if os.path.isfile(old_file.path):
            os.remove(old_file.path)
```

- I think one of the apps I’ve built a while back used this code in production, but nevertheless use at your own risk.
- For example, there’s a **possible data loss** scenario: your data might end up referencing a nonexistent file if your `save()` method call happens to be within a transaction that gets rolled back. You could consider wrapping file-removing logic into `transaction.on_commit()`, along the lines of `transaction.on_commit(lambda: os.remove(old_file.path))`, [as suggested in Mikhail’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield/16041527?noredirect=1#comment123201393_16041527). `django-cleanup` library [does something along those lines](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup/blob/2bc1a08d6363d9a3c130ec0f2ed26be5b940af33/src/django_cleanup/handlers.py#L102-L120).
- Edge case: if your app uploads a new file and points model instance to the new file without calling `save()` (e.g. by bulk updating a `QuerySet`), the old file will keep lying around because signals won’t be run. This doesn’t happen if you use conventional file handling methods.
- Coding style: this example uses `file` as field name, which is not a good style because it clashes with the built-in `file` object identifier.

#### Addendum: periodic cleanup

Realistically, you may want to *also* run a periodic task to handle orphan file cleanup in case a runtime failure prevents some file from being removed. With that in mind, you could probably get rid of signal handlers altogether, and make such a task *the* mechanism for dealing with insensitive data and not-so-large files.

Either way though, if you *are* handling sensitive data, it’s always better to double- or triple- check that you never fail to timely delete data in production to avoid any associated liabilities.

#### See also

- [`FieldFile.delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete) in Django 1.11 model field reference (note that it describes the `FieldFile` class, but you’d call `.delete()` directly on the field: `FileField` instance proxies to the corresponding `FieldFile` instance, and you access its methods as if they were field’s)

  > Note that when a model is deleted, related files are not deleted. If you need to cleanup orphaned files, you’ll need to handle it yourself (for instance, with a custom management command that can be run manually or scheduled to run periodically via e.g. cron).
- Why Django doesn’t delete files automatically: [entry in release notes for Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.3/#deleting-a-model-doesn-t-delete-associated-files)

  > In earlier Django versions, when a model instance containing a `FileField` was deleted, `FileField` took it upon itself to also delete the file from the backend storage. This opened the door to several data-loss scenarios, including rolled-back transactions and fields on different models referencing the same file. In Django 1.3, when a model is deleted the `FileField`’s `delete()` method won’t be called. If you need cleanup of orphaned files, you’ll need to handle it yourself (for instance, with a custom management command that can be run manually or scheduled to run periodically via e.g. cron).
- [Example of using a `pre_delete` signal only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab/14310174#14310174)

Comment: It's probably better to use `instance.song.delete(save=False)`, since it uses the correct django storage engine.

Comment: Found a bug in this where if the instance exists, but no image was previously saved, then `os.path.isfile(old_file.path)` fails because `old_file.path` raises an error (no file is associated with the field). I fixed it by adding `if old_file:` just before the call to `os.path.isfile()`.

Comment: @three_pineapples makes sense. It could be that the NOT NULL constraint on the file field was bypassed or didn’t exit at some point, in which case some objects would have it empty.

Comment: Doesn't work! I get `This backend doesn't support absolute paths.`

Comment: I think this answer is nice but got far too much votes. And I also implemented my universal version :o) However, this issue should be handled by a library, probably automatically. (It turns out, there's a library for exatly this. See: `pip install django-cleanup`)

Comment: it's better to call `transaction.on_commit(lambda: os.remove(old_file.path))` because if you remove a file and then transaction rollback occurs, you lost a file

Comment: @Mikhail fair point, edited to add. `django-cleanup` appears to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 118):

Try [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup), it automatically invokes delete method on FileField when you remove model.

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
)
```

Comment: Cool, it's need to be added to FileField by default,  thanks!

Comment: It is deleting the file while uploading as well

Comment: Wow. I was trying to get this not to happen and I couldn't figure out why it was. Someone had installed this years ago and forgotten about it. Thanks.

Comment: So, why Django removed filefield delete function in the first place?

Comment: You are the legend !!

Comment: @ha-neul As [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.3/#deleting-a-model-doesn-t-delete-associated-files) says it's to prevent data loss and support rollback.

Comment: @un1t Is there a way to exclude a particular file/files from being deleted? e.g. I would not want my default.png to be deleted. How can I exclude that?

Answer (score 61):

You can delete file from filesystem with calling `.delete` method of file field shown as below with Django >= 1.10:

```
obj = Song.objects.get(pk=1)
obj.song.delete()
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, simple and just works.

Comment: Where do I put this code? In `views.py` or `models.py`?

Comment: @Shayan in `views.py`.

Answer (score 22):

## Django 2.x Solution:

It's very easy to handle file deletion in **Django 2**. I've tried following solution using Django 2 and SFTP Storage and also FTP STORAGE, and I'm pretty sure that it'll work with any other storage managers which implemented `delete` method. (`delete` method is one of the `storage` abstract methods which is supposed to delete the file from the storage, physically!)

Override the `delete` method of the model in a way that the instance deletes its FileFields before deleting itself:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='id', related_name="id_user2")
    song = models.FileField(upload_to='/songs/')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/pictures/', blank=True)
    date_upload = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        self.song.storage.delete(self.song.name)
        self.image.storage.delete(self.image.name)
        super().delete()
```

It works pretty easy for me.
If you want to check if file exists before deletion, you can use `storage.exists`. e.g. `self.song.storage.exists(self.song.name)` will return a `boolean` representing if the song exists. So it will look like this:

```py
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    # assuming that you use same storage for all files in this model:
    storage = self.song.storage

    if storage.exists(self.song.name):
        storage.delete(self.song.name)

    if storage.exists(self.image.name):
        storage.delete(self.image.name)

    super().delete()
```

#### EDIT (In Addition):

As [@HeyMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606766/heyman) mentioned, with this solution calling `Song.objects.all().delete()` does not delete files! This is happening because `Song.objects.all().delete()` is running delete query of [Default Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#default-managers). So if you want to be able to delete files of a model by using `objects` methods, you must write and use a [Custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) (just for overriding its delete query):

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def delete(self):
        for obj in self.get_queryset():
            obj.delete()
```

and for assigning the `CustomManager` to the model, you must initial `objects` inside your model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='id', related_name="id_user2")
    song = models.FileField(upload_to='/songs/')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/pictures/', blank=True)
    date_upload = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    objects = CustomManager() # just add this line of code inside of your model

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        self.song.storage.delete(self.song.name)
        self.image.storage.delete(self.image.name)
        super().delete()
```

Now you can use `.delete()` in the end of any `objects` sub-queries. I wrote the simplest `CustomManager`, but you can do it better by returning something about objects you deleted or whatever you want.

Comment: Yeah, I think they added that feature since I posted the question.

Comment: Still delete is not called wenn calling Song.objects.all().delete().  Same for when Instance gets deleted by on_delete=models.CASCADE.

Comment: @HeyMan I solved it and edited my solution right now :)

Comment: I'd love your solution! Unfortunately, this one still does not call delete when I call `delete()` on a `QuerySet`. As per the documentation, even in Django 3, also the `post_delete` signal has to be implemented for full implementation.

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs tnx, did you try using `CustomManager` I suggested in second part of this answer? I'll check Django 3 and update the answer, tnx for mentioning that :)

Comment: @Hamidreza Yes, and I was very surprised that it didn't work. After implementing the answers on this post, I've found `django_cleanup` that works also with QuerySet, without any setup.

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs If you are using a custom queryset, maybe you should override its `delete` method (like what I did in the `CustomManager`) and then initial `objects` by `CustomQuerySet.as_manager()`.

Answer (score 20):

You can also simply overwrite the delete function of the model to check for file if it exists and delete it before calling the super function.

```
import os

class Excel(models.Model):
    upload_file = models.FileField(upload_to='/excels/', blank =True)   
    uploaded_on = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)


    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if os.path.isfile(self.upload_file.path):
            os.remove(self.upload_file.path)

        super(Excel, self).delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Beware that calling `queryset.delete()` won't clean up the files with this solution. You would need to iterate over the queryset and call `.delete()` on each object.

Comment: I am new to Django. This is good, but what if the model was inheriting from an abstract class that has overriden the delete method, wouldn't this override that from the abstract class? Using signals appears better to me

Answer (score 5):

Here is an app that will remove old files whenever model is deleted or a new file is uploaded: [django-smartfields](https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields)

```
from django.db import models
from smartfields import fields

class Song(models.Model):
    song = fields.FileField(upload_to='/songs/')
    image = fields.ImageField(upload_to='/pictures/', blank=True)
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. This is the cleanest solution and also the possibly best implementation, since it is a library so people can always contribute.

Comment: No, unfortunately django-smartfields has a bug probably, because it won't delete my files at least not when using `QuerySet`s. Maybe `django-cleanup`?

Answer (score 5):

For those who look for an answer in a newer version of Django (currently 3.1).

I found this [website](https://cmljnelson.blog/2020/06/22/delete-files-when-deleting-models-in-django/) and it worked for me without any changes, just add it in your `models.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models
 
""" Only delete the file if no other instances of that model are using it"""    
def delete_file_if_unused(model,instance,field,instance_file_field):
    dynamic_field = {}
    dynamic_field[field.name] = instance_file_field.name
    other_refs_exist = model.objects.filter(**dynamic_field).exclude(pk=instance.pk).exists()
    if not other_refs_exist:
        instance_file_field.delete(False)
""" Whenever ANY model is deleted, if it has a file field on it, delete the associated file too"""
@receiver(post_delete)
def delete_files_when_row_deleted_from_db(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for field in sender._meta.concrete_fields:
        if isinstance(field,models.FileField):
            instance_file_field = getattr(instance,field.name)
            delete_file_if_unused(sender,instance,field,instance_file_field)
            
""" Delete the file if something else get uploaded in its place"""
@receiver(pre_save)
def delete_files_when_file_changed(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    # Don't run on initial save
    if not instance.pk:
        return
    for field in sender._meta.concrete_fields:
        if isinstance(field,models.FileField):
            #its got a file field. Let's see if it changed
            try:
                instance_in_db = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
            except sender.DoesNotExist:
                # We are probably in a transaction and the PK is just temporary
                # Don't worry about deleting attachments if they aren't actually saved yet.
                return
            instance_in_db_file_field = getattr(instance_in_db,field.name)
            instance_file_field = getattr(instance,field.name)
            if instance_in_db_file_field.name != instance_file_field.name:
                delete_file_if_unused(sender,instance,field,instance_in_db_file_field)
```

Answer (score 3):

@Anton Strogonoff

I missing something in the code when a file change, if you create a new file generate an error, becuase is a new file a did not find a path. I modified the code of function and added a try/except sentence and it works well.

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=MediaFile)
def auto_delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Deletes file from filesystem
    when corresponding `MediaFile` object is changed.
    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return False

    try:
        old_file = MediaFile.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).file
    except MediaFile.DoesNotExist:
        return False

    new_file = instance.file
    if not old_file == new_file:
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(old_file.path):
                os.remove(old_file.path)
        except Exception:
            return False
```

Comment: I haven't encountered this—could be a bug in my code, or something changed in Django. I would suggest catching specific exception in your `try:` block, though (`AttributeError` perhaps?).

Comment: It is not so good idea to use os library, since you will encounter issues if you migrate to different storage (Amazon S3, for example).

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy what would happen in a storage like Amazon S3 when you use os.remove ??

Comment: @DanielGonzálezFernández I guess it will fail (with error like something about non-existing path). That's why Django uses abstractions for storages.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is as simple as deleting the file/image from the object, then deleting the object itself.

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_song' song.id %}" value="Delete">Delete</a>
```

urls.py

```
path('delete_song/<str:id>', views.delete_song, name='delete_song'),
```

views.py

```
def delete_song(request, id):
    song_to_delete = Song.objects.get(pk=id)
    song_to_delete.image.delete() # delete the file/image
    song_to_delete.delete() # finally delete the object
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 1):

In django 4 this works well for single objects or queries:

```
admin.py
    
class MyFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def delete_model(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.myFile.delete()  
            obj.delete()
     
    list_display = ( 'myFile', 'pk')
    actions = [delete_model]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will run every time i upload a new image (logo field) and check if a logo already exists if so, close it and remove it from disk. The same procedure could of course be made in receiver function. Hope this helps.

```
 #  Returns the file path with a folder named by the company under /media/uploads
    def logo_file_path(instance, filename):
        company_instance = Company.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        if company_instance.logo:
            logo = company_instance.logo
            if logo.file:
                if os.path.isfile(logo.path):
                    logo.file.close()
                    os.remove(logo.path)

        return 'uploads/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.name.lower(), filename)


    class Company(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_("Company"), null=False, blank=False, unique=True, max_length=100) 
        logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=logo_file_path, default='')
```