# How to remove images uploaded with django-ckeditor?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have uploaded some images within the CKEditor in the Django admin interface. I can browse and select images by clicking the "Image" button in the editor, and then click "Browse Server" in the window that pops up. Here is a screenshot of the pop-up:

[image: Screenshot of the pop-up of CKEditor]

My question is: How can I delete images on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is true. Django-ckeditor does not provide any built-in solution for that problem. Information about uploaded files are not stored anywhere.

If you want to keep them - you have to do it by yourself!

Create the appropriate **data model** with the overridden *delete* method (or use any of ready "smart fields" which can handle removal of files for you, [Django delete FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield)):

```
from django.db import models

class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    uploaded_file = models.FileField(upload_to=u"storage/")
    uploaded_at = models.DateField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.uploaded_file.path)

    def url(self):
        return self.uploaded_file.url

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        file_storage, file_path = self.uploaded_file.storage, self.uploaded_file.path
        super(UploadedFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        file_storage.delete(file_path)
```

Provide your own implementation of "*upload*" (and optional "*browse*") view, which will be used to memorize transactions:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from ckeditor_uploader.views import upload, browse
from .models import UploadedFile
import re

@staff_member_required
@csrf_exempt
def ckeditor_upload_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = upload(request, *args, **kwargs)

    if b"Invalid" not in response.content:
        try:
            matched_regex = re.search("callFunction\(\d, '(.*)'\);", str(response.content))
            file_location = matched_regex.group(1).lstrip(settings.MEDIA_URL)
            UploadedFile(uploaded_file=file_location).save()
        except Exception:
            pass
    return response

@staff_member_required
@csrf_exempt
@never_cache
def ckeditor_browse_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return browse(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Change default redirects in **urls.py**:

```
...
from app.views import ckeditor_upload_wrapper, ckeditor_browse_wrapper

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^ckeditor/upload/', ckeditor_upload_wrapper, name='ckeditor_upload'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/browse/', ckeditor_browse_wrapper, name='ckeditor_browse'),
    ...
]
```

and that's all... Now if you *register* your new **UploadedFile** model, you will grant tha ability to browse, search and remove any of uploaded pictures directly from the Django Admin panel.

(This solution was implemented for *Django 1.10* with extension *django-ckeditor 5.3* )

Comment: Such an underrated answer! I was thinking of doing something similar but you saved me the trouble of writing out most of the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible with ckeditor (at least I see no such functionality out-of-the-box).

You can use a django file manager

https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-managers/

For example, [django-filebrowser](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-filebrowser/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this solution:

```
class Post(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField('titulo', max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField('conteudo', blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField('data', blank=True, null=True)
    obs = models.CharField('obs', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-post_date']
        verbose_name = 'notícia'
        verbose_name_plural = 'notícias'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return resolve_url('core:post_detail', slug=self.slug)

    def get_exter_url(self):
        return resolve_url('external:post_detail', slug=self.slug)

    def get_firt_img(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.content, "html.parser")
        imgs = soup.find_all("img")
        return imgs[0]['src'] if len(imgs) > 0 else ''

    def get_link_imgs(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.content, "html.parser")
        imgs = soup.find_all("img")
        list_img = []
        for element in imgs:
            list_img.append(element['src'])

        return list_img

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            unique_slugify(self, self.title, slug_field_name='slug')

        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


# signal Post
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Post)
def remov_to_imgs(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for img in instance.get_link_imgs():
        _file = urllib.parse.unquote(str(settings.BASE_DIR)+img)
        # get thumb the img
        ext = '.'+''.join(_file.split('.')[-1])
        thumb = _file[:-len(ext)]+'_thumb'+ext
        exists = os.path.isfile(_file)
        if exists:
            if not Post.objects.filter(content__icontains=img).exclude(
                pk=instance.pk).exists():
                os.remove(_file)
                # thumb img
                if os.path.isfile(thumb):
                    os.remove(thumb)
```