# Django how do I delete pictures on the server if the image on ckeditor is deleted

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have uploaded some images within the CKEditor, and uploaded images are stored on the server, when I delete the image on the editor, the image stored on the server is not deleted.

Django  2.2, python 3.7, postgresql.

my question: can I set it on ckeditor or on models?

if can how to create a condition when the upload image is automatically deleted when removed on ckeditor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django delete FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield)

Comment: i know, what about the implementation of ckeditor, I find it difficult about that?

Comment: did you see this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201258/how-to-remove-images-uploaded-with-django-ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

You can create an api that delete the image on the server when user delete it on the editor.

Define the url like:

```
url_patterns = [
    path('delete-image', delete_image, name='delete_image'),
]
```

The api view where you delete the image on server:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def delete_image(request):
   # Delete image
```

jQuery scripts:

```
    <when image is deleted on editor>{
       $.post(url, data, function(data, status){
       })
    }
```