# django model automation possible?

Tags: python, django

I have a small problem with django, i'm beginner, and i would like to delete a file right before a new one is uploaded.
I use this in my model.py

```
class Object(models.Model):
    photo1 = models.ImageField('main image', upload_to='%Y/%m/%d', max_length=200)
```

It works well for upload, but it keep the old image on hard drive.
I can do a script to delete or move to a trash directory the file, but it's a bit problematic when using the django admin interface, because it won't update as i want.
Is there a good way to delete the old photo1 variable object before storing the new one?
Thanks for any help!
(sorry for bad english)

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield

Answer (score 0):

Don't exist a automatically way to delete a file. You will need to do this manually using the package os or the image field for delete the file.

I recommend you to use signals to introduce this behavior. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/signals/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, signals seems to do the job but i miss now the pure python code to deal with os (i'm new to python too :))

Edit: I finally just installed django-cleanup with pip and he do all that job alone, I just had to change ImageField for FileField because it doesnt have a file attribute.
Cordially.