# Django delete() command

Tags: python, django, django-models, media-queries, filefield

I'm building a web app in Django. There I have a model `DocFile` with a FileField `upload`.

```
class DocFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Bezeichnung', max_length=100)
    md5sum = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    upload = models.FileField('Datei', upload_to=media_file_name, storage=MediaFileSystemStorage())
```

In the following view, I try to delete the database entry (not the file in my media dir) of DocFile where pk=pd.

```
def delete_doc(request, pd, pk):
    doc = get_object_or_404(DocFile, pk=pd)
    doc.delete()
    return redirect('list_docfile', pk=pk)
```

But sadly the delete() command deletes both the database entry and the file in the media dir. 
I tried to search for a solution but all I got was this:
[Django delete FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield)

If Django removed the function that delete() removes the file of the FileField, why does the command still removes both in my Django application.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Good point old Django would automatically delete both newer versions woudn't

Comment: I'm using Django Version 2.0.1

Comment: So, that's weird. Django 2 does NOT delete file on disk when the corresponding DB entry is deleted. Are you sure your project does not use a third part module that delete this file. Something like `django-cleanup`?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks a lot! I had django-cleanup added in my settings.py in installed_apps. I added it along the way but it did not fulfill my requests so I totally forgot about that modul.