# How to delete existing image while uploading new image in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let say I have a model which has a profile pic image field.As a user I uploaded a profile pic.When I upload a new profile pic, old profile has to get deleted.
How to handle this scenario in development and production stage

Comment: could you please attach some code. FG: `viewsets.py`, `serializer.py`, `models.py`

Answer (score 0):

Use `django-cleanup`, it automatically deletes unnecessary files from server.

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

And add it to your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_cleanup'
]
```

Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28986357/7320045