# How do I automatically delete images in Django media file when I delete the objects in Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-media

please help!
I am using Django 3 and have a basic blog with a title, description and image for each entry.
In Django admin I can delete each blog post however, when I look in my media file in Atom all the images are still there and I have to manually delete them...

how do I get them to auto delete when I delete them in Admin?

Model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/road.jpg')
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blog

def home (request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    return render (request,'blog/home.html', {'blogs':blogs})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Django Admin to delete files when I remove an object from the database/model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab)

Comment: Also, this might be helpful - [Django delete FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield)

Comment: use it forgienkey(on_delete = models.CASCAD)  !!  in you'r model.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
    blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)
    if blog.image:
        if os.path.isfile(blog.image.path):
           os.remove(blog.image.path)
```

Or You Can Use signlas:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Blog)
def mymodel_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
    instance.file.delete(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup) app for automatically remove the media when you delete your objects.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete media files in different ways, but the most easy and convenient way is to delete them with the help of models. Just override the delete() method and delete that object in that custom delete() method.

- **models.py**

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # Other fields in your model
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    
    # Media file field
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.media_file.delete()
        super(YourModel, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

What does the above code do? When you execute the delete() method, it will automatically delete the media file as well.

- **views.py**

```
def sampleView(request):
    model = YourModel.objects.get(id=id)
    model.delete()
```