# Remove file objects from children models on delete

Tags: python, django

My model `File` has as main purpose to link multiple `file`s for one `Invoice`.

```
class File(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name = 'files', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'storage/invoicing/')
    
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file.delete()
        return super(File, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

When i delete one instance of my model `File`, the `file` stored in `storage/invoicing` is also deleted because of my modified `delete()` method.

However, if i delete the instance from the parent model `Invoice`, the `file` is not deleted. Even with the `File` instance being removed from the database, the `file` is still acessable.

How can i code the parent model to delete everything from the children model, including the files?

I've searched a bit and i know that probably signals like `post_delete` can help me here, but i really don't know how to code it.

Comment: check this question's answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield

Comment: @ishakO. I tried signals and the file is still accessible. The `Invoice` gets deleted but the file is still on the server. I'm using an aws s3 bucket for storage, i don't know if that changes anything btw

Answer (score 0):

`pre_delete` signal can help you to solve the problem.

*your_app/signals.py*

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete

from your_app.models import Invoice


def remove_files(instance, **kwargs):
    for file_obj in instance.files.all():
        file_obj.file.delete()


pre_delete.connect(remove_files, sender=Invoice)
```

**IMPORTANT!**

As you might have guessed, `pre_delete` signal calls the specified function before deleting the object(in this case instance of `Invoice` class). It means that before removing the invoice and all related file objects(because of CASCADE), it will delete all files associated with the file objects that refer to the invoice. **If for some reason deletion won't happen you'll lose files anyway**.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work for me. I just copied the code you gave me and the `Invoice` gets deleted, but the `file` is still accessible if i keep the url of the file storage. I forgot to mention but, the `file` storage is located in a aws s3 bucket. I'm not sure if that changes anything

Comment: Btw, i think you have a typo. `invoice.files.all()` should be `instance.files.all()` right? Anyway, i tried both ways and no success still

Comment: Yes it should be instance.files.all().