# Django - Delete file associated with ImageField attribute of Model

Tags: python, django

So I have a model called `User`, which has an `avatar` field, which is just the user's avatar. I want to be able to delete the file whenever the user chooses to delete their avatar. As you can see below in my `view.py` I retrieve the current user object from the `request`(This is because I take the user uuid from the access token given to make the request then query the user object). Then I call `delete` on the `avatar` attribute, but I don't know if this actually deletes the file as well. My assumption is that it just deletes that attribute `url`. **How do I delete the file associated with ImageField when I delete a ImageField attribute in a model?**

`model.py`

```
class User(AbstractDatesModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=USERNAME_MAX_LEN, unique=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(USERNAME_MIN_LEN)])
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

`view.py`

```
@api_view(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def multi_method_user_avatar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Some POST code
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            request.user.avatar.delete()
            request.user.save()

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(dict(error=str(e), user_message=generic_error_user_msg),
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django delete FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield)

Comment: @HaoLan yea I would say so, but the person below gave a quicker more direct answer.

Comment: I just want to tell you ,try searching a question before putting a question.

Comment: And do `os.remove` is not a good method,if you use other filesystem,not local filesystem,such object storage.

Comment: @HaoLan I did search. I just wasn't sure if there were different intricacies between ImageFileField and FileField. For example, perhaps ImageFileField has built in functionality to remove files.

Comment: @HaoLan they're also using `os.remove` in the post you suggested as an answer as well. What should be used instead?

Comment: just `avatar.delete()`. You may have a read about the storage api about django:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/storage/.

Comment: @HaoLan are you saying avatar.delete() is enough?

Comment: In my option,Yes.You can have a try.

Comment: actually I don't think `os.remove` works because if you're connected to an Amazon S3 server you don't have OS access.

Comment: Yeah,try to use `delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.user.avatar.delete()`
is sufficient. I ran a test that checks if the file exists prior to calling that end point and is deleted post calling the endpoint and it passes. Using `os.remove` doesn't work on deployed server because you don't have access to their file system at that level.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting an ImageField keeps the file on the system.

Change your code to this to delete the file:

```
#insert at top of file
import os

elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    try:
        os.remove(request.user.avatar.path)
        request.user.avatar.delete()
        request.user.save()
```

Comment: sorry I have to unselect this as the answer this doesn't work when you connect your Django app to S3, because you don't have os access to S3

Comment: Your question doesn't say the image is on an S3 bucket.

Comment: Yea sorry thought it was apparent since normally you deploy a site.

Comment: Even with that assumption there are more CDNs than S3

Comment: Just replace the os.remove() with whatever the S3 API is for deleting a file.

Comment: Apparently .delete just works