# Django - Replace file of a FileField with file from another FileField

Tags: django, django-models, filefield

I have two models both having `FileField` like so:

```
class OriginalFile(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=file_path)

class RevisedFile(models.Model):
    newfile = models.FileField(upload_to=revisedfile_path)
    originalfile = models.ForeignKey(OriginalFile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

As you see, when uploading a file for the first time, it gets uploaded to `file_path` in the `OriginalFile` model. However, if a user uploads a revised edition of the same file, it gets saved to `revisedfile_path` in the `RevisedFile` model.

The normal user doesn't have the rights to revise a file by herself(which is why I'm not replacing the original file at that moment). If a manager accepts the revised file, then following things need to happen:

1. Replace the `docfile` of `OriginalFile` with `newfile` of `RevisedFile`
2. Delete the related instance of `RevisedFile` along with its `newfile` saved in the directory.

The names of `docfile` and `newfile` can be assumed to be the same. I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any kind of help woould be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sound like users have access to your filesystem and you upload to different directories to restrict access for non manager users. Is that the case?

Comment: yeah, normal users upload files using a form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any user access to your file system. Use FK instead of manipulating files directly. Do not delete old files, but rather no show the old files.

```
class DocFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_path)  # Single path for all doc files

class Document(models.Model):
    # Optional name, description fields 
    approved = models.FK(DocFile)
    revisions = models.ManyToManyField(DocFile)
```

When normal user uploads a file add it to Document.revisions and if it is the only revision set it as approved as well.

Create a permission group for managers and allowed them to edit Document in admin. This way they can select which of the DocFiles associated with the Document is the approved one. No need to transfer files, you do not lose versions of the file and you file system is safe from rm -r. Manager would also be able to download files for review

Comment: By access to file system, I meant the user can upload a file. Not in any way view/change files or access directory. Also, I figure that going the way you suggested, there'll be many orphaned files, if the users frequently upload revised files. That is one of the things I wanted to avoid. Also, as the revised and original files will have the same name, would that cause any problems?

Comment: You can still delete the files from admin or add extra logic to delete revisions when approved is changed. Orphaned files are nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: You can add upload time to DocFile and have a cronjob delete files if the approved DocFile is was uploaded last of all the revisions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this.. However, I found an interesting solution which deletes the file along with the instance.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab)