# How replace an old image for another image in django admin?

Tags: python, django, filefield

I would like replace from django admin, one image for another and delete the old image.
This is my models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Nom", max_length=64)

    machine = models.ManyToManyField(Maquina, verbose_name=u"Maquina/es", related_name='name_machine')
    reference = models.ManyToManyField(Referencia, verbose_name=u"Referencia/es", related_name='references')

    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos', verbose_name=u"Video")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='fotos_video', verbose_name=u"Imatge")
```

What function can I use for this?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't opening the Django Admin and uploading a new image in the `photo` field work?

Comment: No, the old image stay in the directory, but not is remove

Answer (score 0):

Django does not auto-remove files for you (think of it as a safety mechanism). If you want the photo removed, a good thing to do is use the `pre_save` signal with the `Video` model as a sender, check if the image has changed and if it did, `os.unlink` the old image.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab) is a close enough example for this.