# django: calling delete on object doesn't delete the file

Tags: python, django

So I have the following model.

```
class StoreSegments01(models.Model):
    segment = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    segmentID = models.TextField(max_length=100, default=11)

class StoreSegments01Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = StoreSegments01
    fields = ['segment', 'segmentID']

def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '{0}'.format(instance.segmentID)
```

I want to provide a way for the users to delete their files. In manage.py shell I try the following:

```
obj = StoreSegments01.objects.get(segmentID='239fd363-562a-41b3-a915-b7a84cc4a172')
>>> obj.delete()
```

It deletes the record related to the specified segmentID, but the file associated with the ID is still there. I tried the same with queryset, still the file is not deleted.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get Django Admin to delete files when I remove an object from the database/model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab)

Comment: @Variant Do I have to go with signals?

Comment: Or just install `pip install django-cleanup` as one of the answers mention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative to using signals: override the `delete` method of your model.

Example:

```
class StoreSegments01(models.Model):
    segment = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    segmentID = models.TextField(max_length=100, default=11)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first, delete the file
        self.segment.delete(save=False)

        # now, delete the object
        super(StoreSegments01, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

For Python 3, call `super` like this: `super().delete(*args, **kwargs)`

**Heads up! :** This works if you delete individual objects. But if you delete objects in bulk, the associated files aren't deleted. Because deleting a single object calls `model.delete()` method but deleting in bulk calls `queryset.delete()` method. Thanks to [Håken Lid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977847/) who pointed this out in a comment below.

Comment: You can use `django.db.models.signals.pre_delete` instead of overriding the `delete()` method. Signals will listen to both model.delete() and queryset.delete(). Docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/

Comment: @HåkenLid Hey, thanks. Now I understand why files weren't deleting using bulk delete.

Comment: You made my day, thany you a lot, it was very simple :D `self.segment.delete(save=False)` and also `super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)`